# How to best way define the main object in the polymorphic relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I have models:

dress.rb

```
class Dress < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end
```

publication.rb

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :name, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have two ideas how its write:

1. Add `main_image_id` (:integer) to Image, Publication and other models. Also can create a relation `has_one :main_image, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :main_image_id`. But this is bad way because this field need add to every created Model which has polymorphic relations with Image.
2. Add `main` (:boolean) to Image. And check every time true or false. This is bad way too because table `images` will have unused fields.
   Who has any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd way is better. this way you can order images by this field and make scopes.

```
# image.rb
  scope main, ->{where(main: true)}
# publication.rb
  scope images, ->{images.order(:main)}

@images.main #=> will give you needed result as 
@publiscations.images #=> will give you first image as main.
```

And if you think about extra column, you will need to add it anyway. So why not to use it where it is more useful

Comment: Thanks, now I'm going to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

**STI**

Maybe [try STI](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/45-use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads)

```
#app/models/asset.rb
Class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :name, ImageUploader
end

#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < Asset
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  delegate :url, to: :asset #-> not used Carrierwave, so I don't know how this is done
end

#app/models/dress.rb
Class Dress < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, as :imageable
end

#app/models/publication.rb
Class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, as :imageable
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/dresses_controller.rb
Class DressesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @dresses = Dress.all
   end
end

#app/views/dresses/index.html.erb
<% @dresses.each do |dress| %>
   <%= dress.images.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image.url %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it is more suitable for models more than me and it does not solve my problem

Comment: Okay no problem do you want me to delete?

Comment: No! Let your answer will be - it expands the horizons of building relationships between models